# How to combine these two commands?: ./script.sh > logfile.log and ./script.sh 2> logfile.log

Tags: bash, logging, logfile

How to combine these two commands?

```
./script.sh > logfile.log
```

and

```
./script.sh 2> logfile.log
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do you mean _combine_? You want both of their output to go to the log file?

Comment: Is it two different scripts? If so then use: `./s1.sh > log; ./s2.sh 2>> log` see the append `>>`

Comment: It's one script and I do want both of their output to go to the log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, to redirect both standard output and standard error to the same file, you can write

```
./script.sh &> logfile.log
```

If you want to be compatible with other shells,

```
./script.sh > logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: The first only works in bash 4+

Comment: When you are logging, you might need to append log file instead of overwriting it, so simple change to `./script.sh >> logfile.log 2>&1`.

Comment: thank you! second option works perfect )